# How do I create a text list of open files in Sublime Text 2

Tags: file, sublimetext2

Hi there and thanks in advance for any help on this.

I have tried hunting here and other places on the web but have not found anything to help.  If this is obvious or has been asked before then I am sorry.

I am using Sublime Text 2 and I often end up with a load of open files because they meet a criteria that I have been working on.

I would like to list all those files out a new text file, within Sublime text.

Something like: 
for each open file
    write filename (or possibly full filepath)
Next

I know I can get there from the open files panel but that only lists the files, there is no interaction with it that does what I expected.  To thought I might be able to highlight files and use copy and paste to get a list.

Is this a built-in function that I have missed?  Is there already a package to do this?  Will I have to work out how to write a plug-in to do this?

Once again, many thanks for any and all assistance on this.

(If it makes any difference this is Sublime text 2, mostly on Windows but I do also switch across to Mac regularly for different jobs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hacky and relatively quick way to get something like that:

1. `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F` (This brings up the `Find in files` dialog)
2. Make sure the Regex mode is on (`.*` button) and search after `$`, for example
3. You now have a large file with all the content. Hope not too large to slow Sublime down. Now hit `Ctrl`+`F` for normal `Search` dialog
4. Enter `^_` (caret+space, not underscore) and hit `Find All`
5. `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`K` to remove all those content lines

There! Now you have a list of all open files with full path.

More concise:

- `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F`
- `.*` button is on, search after `$`
- `Ctrl`+`F`
- `.*` button still on, search after `^[space]` -> `Find All`
- `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`K`

---

The other way is to make yourself a small plugin to do that for you at a keystroke.

From the [SublimeText2 API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html), you can get some useful methods:

```
Class sublime.Window.views()    [View]    Returns all open views in the window.
```

Then

```
Class sublime.View.file_name()    String    The full name file the file
                                            associated with the buffer, or
                                            None if it doesn't exist on disk.
```

You can start from an existing plugin. This involves some Python programming skills, though.

Comment: thanks for this. It certainly is a bit of a kludge - but it seems to work! **As long as you remember to set the Find All filter to open files only!** As the open files were the results of looking through a very large project to find some bits for further analysis I ended up with a Find results of nearly 6 million lines! I'm sure I can work with this in the interim if this is the only way to do it... I would like to believe that there is an easier way - but maybe not! Thanks again for your help - it has been very useful!

Comment: My first idea was to actually FindInFiles for some unique character per file, like EOF, but I couldn't pull that off.

Comment: thanks, the api looks like the way to go.  I have not tried working with it yet.  I should have a look and see what I can do.  I just hoped this was 'baked-in' somewhere...

Comment: curious. not sure I get this. (and I understand regexes). Ctrl-shift-F, choosing regex button, searching for $, lists filenames and all contents of each file.  But I don't get the latter, of removing the contents.   You have a results window showing all filenames and contents of each file. You then do a ctrl-f search(so searching just the results window) for "^ " so any line beginning with a space,  that keeps the contents there and just puts a mark by those lines that start with a space. Focus is still on "^ ", then you do ctrl-shift-k which deletes the current line but that just deletes "^ "

Comment: so after following steps 1-5, all steps. I still have a results window, listing all filenames and their contents.  ctrl-shift-k won't remove the contents of all files from the results window.

Comment: It may happen that `ctrl-shift-k` doesn't delete the line on your setup. Maybe it's OS dependent or you got it overwrited.

Comment: You could try, after step 4. and before step 5., to hit `Left-arrow` once. It might help

Comment: @iuliux  ctrl-shift-k is doing what it's meant to do  according to this link for ctrl+shift+k https://gist.github.com/nuxlli/1207014 . It deletes the line. The line after step 4 says "^ " then ctrl-shift-k only deletes the "^ " which is as expected based on that link. But you say it will "remove all those content lines". It doesn't on my system, and according to that link, it shouldn't, it should only remove that one line. In this case, the one line which has "^ " written in it with a blinking cursor.  So I also don't see the logic in your steps.

Comment: We are definitely not on the same page here :) Sadly, I'm not able to test on OSX.

Comment: Are you sure you have the Regex mode on (`.*` button) at step 4.? Also, you do `Find All`, not only `Find`, right (so that you have a separate cursor at the beginning of each line-to-be-deleted)?

Answer (score 2):

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class RunningfileCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.window().new_file().insert(edit, 0, "\n".join([view.file_name() for view in sublime.active_window().views() if view and view.file_name()]))
```

1. Create file with above code and saved as **filelist.py**
2. Open sublime, Goto Preferences -> Select Browse Pacakages
3. Goto User folder and move above file(**filelist.py**)
4. Now goto Preferences -> Keybinding
5. Add below content on it:

   [{
       "keys": ["f12"],
       "command": "runningfile"
     }]
6. Now press f12, you got your all opened files path in new window

Thanks

Comment: Any idea how to also get the [current cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541616/where-does-sublime-store-the-last-cursor-position-of-a-previosuly-opened-file) for each of those files?